# Android remove blank screen after splash xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a problem which seems pretty common and found loads of suggestions but tried a few and dont work.

1. Create a blank xamarin forms app with a splash screen (Prism
   template comes with a default)
2. Launch the app As soon as the splash
   screen ends you see a white background (very annoying)

Any suggestions?

**Main Activity**

```
    [Activity(Theme = "@style/MainTheme",
              ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            LoadApplication(new App(new AndroidInitializer()));
        }

        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
```

**Splash Activity**

```
    [Activity(Theme = "@style/MainTheme.Splash",
              MainLauncher = true,
              NoHistory = true)]
    public class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        // Launches the startup task
        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();
            StartActivity(new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(MainActivity)));
        }
    }
```

**Styles.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <resources>

      <style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
      </style>
      <style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1976D2</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>   
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
      </style>

      <style name="AppCompatDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
      </style>

      <style name="MainTheme.Splash" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
      </style>
    </resources>
```

Comment: You can add  `<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>` to the `MainActivity.cs`'s style of theme.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply , added that but now the icon on the splash screen dissappears. Am I missing something thanks

Comment: Did you add above property in the splash `MainTheme.Splash`? If so, does `MainActivity.cs` have his own style? You should add `<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>` to `MainActivity.cs`'s style.

Comment: Hi yes, see amended question that is all I have , just created a blank project and added your line as suggested to the mainactivity theme but I still see the blank page.

Comment: `  <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>` to your `MainTheme` style.

Comment: Hi kind of works but I see some sort popup page "flashing" for a second...

Comment: For the new issue, you can open a new thread,